# select option from dropdown box when another element is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a colour picker based on colours specified in a dropdown box with the code below ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf9L3/))

HTML:

```
<select id="colour" name="colour"> 
      <option value="000000">Black</option>
      <option value="CCCCCC">Grey</option>
      <option value="EAEAEA">Light Grey</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
    $(function() {
        var $colourcontainer = '<div id="colour-palette"></div>';
        $( '#colour' ).after( $colourcontainer );

        $( '#colour option' ).each( function() {
            $val = $(this).val();
            if( $val ) {
                $( '#colour-palette' ).append( '<div class="colour" style="background-color:#'+$val+';"></div>' ).click( function() {
                    $('#colour:last').val($val);
                    alert($val);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem I'm having is getting it to loop just once for each dropdown option as right now it loops several times and adds multiple onclicks to each colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds multiple clicks because you are binding a click handler to the `#colour-palette` in each iteration (here 3 iterations).

A better approach would be to create the `.colour` element add the color as a data property and then use the on click handler to assign the click event of `#colour-palette` to `.color` element to the 
Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var $colourcontainer = '<div id="colour-palette"></div>';
    $('#colour').after($colourcontainer);

    $('#colour option').each(function() {
        $val = $(this).val();
        if ($val) {
            var colorEl = $('<div class="colour" style="background-color:#' + $val + ';"></div>');
            colorEl.data("bgColor", $val)
            $('#colour-palette').append(colorEl);
        }
    });
    $('#colour-palette').on("click", ".colour", function() {
        $('#colour').val($(this).data("bgColor"));
    });
});​
```

**Working JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rf9L3/1/

Comment: this is much cleaner. I can see what I was doing wrong now. Thanks for your help